# Memory handling in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I need to perform some operations on a pandas DataFrame() in order to evaluate some measure but leave my DataFrame as is. So I thought that I should start by duplicating it in memory :

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
```

When printing

```
print(id(df1), id(df2))
```

I do get two different system adresses. So in my sense, these are two different instances of DataFrame().

However, if I do:

```
df2['b'] = [4,5,6]
print(df1)
```

df1 appears with a 'b' column, although I only added it in df2.

Why is this happening? 
How can I really duplicate my DataFrame so that operations on one do not modify the other? 
I am on Python 3.5 and pandas 0.24.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [pd.DataFrame.copy](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html)

```
df2 = df1.copy()
```

An assignement, even when you assign to a new variable, is referencing the same data/indices in memory, which means a manipulation on df1 or df2 will change the same data in memory. Using copy however, df2 gets its own copy of data that can be manipulated independently.

---

**Explanation**:

Why do you get two different memory addresses when calling the `pd.DataFrame` on a `DataFrame`?

Simply put, `pandas.DataFrame` is a wrapper around `numpy.ndarry`. When you called the `pd.DataFrame` with `df1` dataframe as input, there was a new `pd.DataFrame` wrapper that was created (thus a different memory address), but the data is exactly the same. You can verify that with the following code:

```
In [2]: import pandas as pd
   ...: df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3]})
   ...: df2 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
   ...: 

In [3]: print(id(df1), id(df2))
(4665009296, 4665009360)

In [4]: df1._data
Out[4]: 
BlockManager
Items: Index([u'a'], dtype='object')
Axis 1: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=3, step=1)
IntBlock: slice(0, 1, 1), 1 x 3, dtype: int64

In [5]: id(df1._data)
Out[5]: 4522343248

In [6]: id(df2._data)
Out[6]: 4522343248
```

As you can see, the memory address for `df1._data` and `df2._data` is exactly the same.

This is also clear when you read the `DataFrame` source code [in github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py#L385-L386), where, at the beginning of the constructor, the same data is referenced by the new dataframe:

```
if isinstance(data, DataFrame):
    data = data._data
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you by any chance have an explanation on why adresses were different on my example but object was not copied?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Note however that I did not do a simple assignment but created (or so I thought) a new object using pd.DataFrame(). - I thought it would work in the same way as list() copies a list and its elements.

Comment: @Matina you have two different `DataFrame` objects... but they're both referencing the same underlying `numpy.array`s... The underlying data only gets copied with an explicit `.copy()` call.